# Ruby yield example explanation?

Tags: ruby, block, yield, enumerable

I'm doing a SaaS course with Ruby. On an exercise, I'm asked to calculate the cartesian product of two sequences by using iterators, blocks and yield.

I ended up with this, by pure guess-and-error, and it seems to work. But I'm not sure about how. I seem to understand the basic blocks and yield usage, but this? Not at all.

```
class CartProd
  include Enumerable
  def initialize(a,b)
        @a = a
        @b = b
  end
  def each
        @a.each{|ae|
                @b.each{|be|
                        yield [ae,be]
                }
        }
  end
end
```

Some explanation for a noob like me, please?

(PS: I changed the required class name to CartProd so people doing the course can't find the response by googling it so easily)

Comment: Side note: the class variables @@a and @@b are harmfull (try experimenting with two instances). They should be replaced with @a and @b.

Comment: Thanks, I'll correct it. So @@ defined class variables and @ instance variables.

Comment: Btw, the `include Enumerable` line is unnecessary.

Comment: @manzoid: Unless CartProd is intended to be Enumerable itself.

Comment: @muistooshort: That's a good point. If you want to mix in Enumerable facilities, sure. I think the assignment as stated is a bit different: "calculate the cartesian product of two sequences by using iterators, blocks and yield", so I figured best to keep it as simple as possible and stick to using those constructs. Probably no need for classes and mix-ins just to consider how `yield` and iterators interact, at an intro level. Upvoted the clarification though, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's build this up step-by-step. We will simplify things a bit by taking it out of the class context.

For this example it is intuitive to think of an iterator as being a more-powerful replacement for a traditional for-loop.

So first here's a for-loop version:

```
seq1 = (0..2)
seq2 = (0..2)
for x in seq1
  for y in seq2
    p [x,y] # shorthand for puts [x, y].inspect
  end
end
```

Now let's replace that with more Ruby-idiomatic iterator style, explicitly supplying blocks to be executed (i.e., the `do...end` blocks):

```
seq1.each do |x|
  seq2.each do |y|
    p [x,y]
  end
end
```

So far, so good, you've printed out your cartesian product.  Now your assignment asks you to use `yield` as well.  The point of `yield` is to "yield execution", i.e., pass control to another block of code temporarily (optionally passing one or more arguments).

So, although it's not *really* necessary for this toy example, instead of directly printing the value like above, you can `yield` the value, and let the caller supply a block that accepts that value and prints it instead.

That could look like this:

```
 def prod(seq1, seq2)
    seq1.each do |x|
      seq2.each do |y|
        yield [x,y]
      end
    end
  end
```

Callable like this:

```
prod (1..2), (1..2) do |prod| p prod end
```

The `yield` supplies the product for each run of the inner loop, and the yielded value is printed by the block supplied by the caller.

Comment: Just to add: a simpler way of writing this is `yield seq1.product(seq2)`

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you not understand here? You've made an iterator that yields all possible pairs of elements. If you pass `CartProd#each` a block, it will be executed `a.length*b.length` times. It's like having two different `for` cycles folded one into another in any other programming language.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what a yield is doing there exactly

Comment: It's just executing a block if your method call has one. Any arguments you specify in yield call will be passed to block.

Comment: `yield [ae,be]` is informing the calling code that the return value is `[ae,be]`. Reading through [Using the Enumerable Module](http://ruby.about.com/od/advancedruby/ss/Using-The-Enumerable-Module.htm) in detail should help you understand how the example works.

Comment: I think I understand now! So there's a block called each defined by the Enumerable module that gets the job done. Right? That has sense to what I read until now about the usage of yield.

Answer (score 0):

*yield* simply passes (yields) control to a block of code that has been passed in as part of the method call. The values after the yield keyword are passed into the block as arguments. Once the block has finished execution it passes back control.

So, in your example you could call #each like this:

```
CartProd.new([1, 2], [3, 4]).each do |pair|
  # control is yielded to this block
  p pair
  # control is returned at end of block
end
```

This would output each pair of values.